# JQuery : simulate player moving on the field

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, image, motion

I'm trying to simulate a player moving on the field (e.g. `div` element in this case, being the player an `img` element). How do I go about making the `img` move smoothly in the beginning, progressively speeding up until it reached the "top speed" and continue to do it unless the end of the route is near enough to do the 2 initial steps again but backwards to simulate the stopping.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aPNKQ/

**html**

```
 <div>Help</div>
```

**jq**

```
$(function (){
    $('div').animate({left: '100px'},5000);
    setTimeout(function (){
        $('div').stop(false,false).animate({left: '100px'},2000);
    },1000);
})
```

**CSS**

```
div{background: red; float: left;position: absolute; left: 0;}
```

with alittle imagination you could make the speed 5000,4000, dynamic etc... there you go :)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Actually `animate()` has it's own easing methods, so there's no need to use `setTimeout()` to perform aditional effects, but it will be usefull to perform a player's turnaround. Cheers! :)